# When you use a cellular connection how is your internet connection encrypted

Tags: encryption, mobile, cellular

When you use a cellular connection how is your internet connection encrypted?

Usually there is some sort of key like with WIFI the wifi password is the key used to encrypt data?

How does encryption work on a cellular network when connecting the the internet?

Does it use the AT&T password on your account?

For example if I log into a bank on my phone is that password sent encrypted all the way?

Comment: This is what you are looking for in terms of technical specifics: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99559/cellular-encryption-algorithms-currently-in-use-globally

Comment: @schroeder A little too complex for me to understand

Comment: I'd suggest that your question is how communication channel encryption works in general. That might be a little outside our scope.

Answer (score 1):

While the cellular connection does implement a level of protection on certain segments, that's really not pertinent. Even if the cellular network is completely in the clear, it's the *HTTP**S*** encrypted connection to your bank that protects your password **all the way to the bank**.

No, none of the other passwords matter.

Comment: Do the mobile banking apps have an https connection?

Comment: @Luke F - It would be insane for any bank to **not** use HTTPS.